# How to design a keras functional API that takes 4-dimensional data and performs classification

Tags: keras, tf.keras

The input data (X) has the shape : (x, 1, y, 1)

The corresponding output data (Y) has the shape : (x, 1, 5) (5-class classification)

The following is some code to a functional model that accepts the above data and performs 5 class classification.

```
def lstm_model(n_classes=5, use_sub_layer=False, use_rnn=True, verbose=False):
    inputLayer = Input(shape=(1, 3000, 1), name='inLayer')
    conv = MaxPool1D(pool_size=8, strides=8, name='fMaxP1')(conv)
    conv = Dropout(rate=0.5, name='fDrop1')(conv)
    conv = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=8, padding='same', activation='relu', 
    name='fConv2')(conv)
    conv = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=8, padding='same', activation='relu', 
    name='fConv3')(conv)
    conv = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=8, padding='same', activation='relu', 
    name='fConv4')(conv)
    conv = MaxPool1D(pool_size=4, strides=4, name='fMaxP2')(conv)
    convShape = conv.get_shape()
    conv = Flatten(name='fFlat1')(conv)
    conv1 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=Fs*4, strides=int(Fs/2), padding='same', 
    activation='relu', name='cConv1')(inputLayer)
    conv1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=4, strides=4, name='cMaxP1')(conv1)
    conv1 = Dropout(rate=0.5, name='cDrop1')(convCoarse)
    conv1 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=6, padding='same', activation='relu', 
    name='cConv2')(conv1)
    conv1 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=6, padding='same', activation='relu', 
    name='cConv3')(conv1)
    conv1 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=6, padding='same', activation='relu', 
    name='cConv4')(conv1)
    conv1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, name='cMaxP2')(conv1)
    conv1Shape = conv1.get_shape()
    conv1 = Flatten(name='cFlat1')(conv1)
    mLayer = concatenate([conv, conv1], name='merge_1')
    outLayer = Dropout(rate=0.5, name='mDrop1')(mLayer)

    outLayer = Reshape((1, outLayer.get_shape()[1]), name='reshape1')(outLayer)
    outLayer = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(outLayer)
    outLayer = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(outLayer)
    outLayer = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax', name='outLayer')(outLayer)
    model = Model(inputLayer, outLayer)
    optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-4)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
    model.summary()
return model

model=lstm_model(verbose=True)
```

The above code however generates the following error:

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer "fMaxP1" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 1, 500, 64)`

Lookin for some help in this regard.

Thank you

Comment: For this you need to use 2D layers, not 1D.

Comment: Replaced Conv1D with Conv2D, and MaxPool1D with MaxPool2D, but got the error ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "fMaxP1" (type MaxPooling2D).

Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 8 from 1 for '{{node fMaxP1/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 8, 8, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 8, 8, 1]](Placeholder)' with input shapes: [?,1,500,64].

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1, 500, 64), dtype=float32) @Dr.Snoopy